# Is there a way to do grep, awk, apply variable in one line rather than 3 like in my example?

Tags: bash

So currently I want to apply a single value in a large text document to a variable to them apply later in my bash script.

The initial text file isn't important but it has a line in amongst a dozen or so others that reads something like the following:

```
x,y,z: 2000 2000 500
```

The x,y,z is unique to the file so I can just grab this line out easily with grep

```
grep x,y,z textfile.txt > xyz.txt
```

Then I am just making a single file with awk

```
awk '{print $4}' xyz.txt > awkoutput.txt
```

Then I am just using cat to apply this to a variable

```
ZDIM=$(cat "awkoutput.txt")
```

The ZDIM is then used later on to instruct a calculation to another text file. This works but I am a bit of bash novice and wondered if there was a more elegant way to write this rather than creating a bunch of text files i need to rm later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `awk` is perfectly capable of performing a regular-expression match, so you can drop `grep`:

```
awk '/x,y,z/ {print $4}' textfile.txt
```

There is no difference between writing `awk`'s output to a file, then capturing the output of `cat`; and simply capturing the output of `awk`. So you can just use

```
ZDIM=$(awk '/x,y,z/ {print $4}' textfile.txt)
```

---

Even if `awk` *couldn't* do regular-expression matching, and `cat` was somehow necessary, you could use a pipeline instead of creating the temporary files.

```
ZDIM=$(grep x,y,z textfile.txt | awk '{print $4}' | cat)
```

Comment: Maybe still ask whether this data really needs to be in a variable. Storing nontrivial amounts of data in a shell variable is often an antipattern.

Comment: At least in this context, it seems legitimate. The OP said that the key is unique, so `awk` is only outputting one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that on the line there're four columns from which the last three are numbers, you could just grab the grep output to a variable.

So for example using `-P` as in perl-style regex, we get look-around assertions to drop part of the output, and `-o` to only output the match:

```
ZDIM=$(grep -oP 'x,y,z: \d+ \d+ \K\d+')
```

Which reads: grep the string `x,y,z:` followed by two groups of digits and only grab the third digit grouping after that and then only output the match.